# How to send a pdf object from Databricks to Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, office365, databricks, fpdf, office365api

**INTRO**: I have a Databricks notebook where I create a *pdf* file based on some data.
In order to generate the file I am using the `fpdf` library:

```
from fpdf import FPDF, HTMLMixin
```

Thanks to the library I generate a pdf file which is of type: `<__main__.HTML2PDF at 0x7f3b73720fd0>`.
My goal now is to send this *pdf* to a sharepoint folder. To do so I am using the following lines of code:

```
from office365.runtime.auth.user_credential import UserCredential
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.sharepoint.files.file import File

# paths
sharepoint_site = "MySharepointSite" 
sharepoint_folder = "Shared Documents/General/PDFs/" 
sharepoint_user = "aaa@bbb.onmicrosoft.com" 
sharepoint_user_pw = "xyz" 
sharepoint_folder = sharepoint_folder.strip("/")

# set environment variables
SITE_URL = f"https://sharepoint.com/sites/{sharepoint_site}"
RELATIVE_URL = f"/sites/{sharepoint_site}/{sharepoint_folder}"

# connect to sharepoint
ctx = ClientContext(SITE_URL).with_credentials(UserCredential(sharepoint_user, sharepoint_user_pw))
web = ctx.web
ctx.load(web).execute_query()

# Generate PDF
pdf = generate_pdf(ctx, row['ServerRelativeUrl'])

# HERE IS MY ISSUE!
ctx.web.get_folder_by_server_relative_url(sharepoint_folder).upload_file('test.pdf', pdf).execute_query()
```

**PROBLEM**: When I reach the last row I get the following error message:

```
TypeError: Object of type HTML2PDF is not JSON serializable
```

I believe that *pdf* objects cannot be serialized to be *JSON* and therefore I am stuck and I do not know how to send the PDF to the sharepoint.

**QUESTION**: Would you be able to suggest a smart and elegant way to achieve my goal i.e sending the *pdf* file to the sharepoint please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by saving the pdf as a string, then encoding it and finally pushing it to the sharepoint:

```
pdf_binary = pdf.output(dest='S').encode("latin1")
ctx.web.get_folder_by_server_relative_url(sharepoint_folder).upload_file("test.pdf", pdf_binary).execute_query()
```

**Note**: If it does not work, try to change the encoding type.